# How to change values of ListItems recursively in Sharepoint 2013 using CSOM

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013, csom

### My Situation

Hi,
my client has a Sharepoint Server 2013 on Premise. He wants to write metadata on multiple files. More specifically he wants to choose a folder and then the application should write the same value in a column for every file/folder in that folder.

### What I already did

I wrote a CAML-query that returns all files/folder below the chosen folder. I then write the value for each item and update it.

### What I want to do

I want to write an application where my client can choose a folder. After that the software should update all files under that folder.
I want to write this application using C# and CSOM.

### My Problem

This is very slow. With multiple thousands of files per folder it takes hours just for one folder to complete.

### My Questions

Is there a way to speed things up?
Can CAML-Query also update values?
What is the recommended way of doing what I want to do?
Is there another way of achieving what my client wants?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take advantage of feature called [Request Batching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798420.aspx), which in turn could dramatically affect the performance by *minimizing the number of messages that are passed between the client and the server*.

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798420.aspx):

> The CSOM programming model is built around request batching. When you
>   work with the CSOM, you can perform a series of data operations on the
>   ClientContext object. These operations are submitted to the server in
>   a single request when you call the `ClientContext.BeginExecuteQuery`
>   method.

For comparison lets demonstrate two ways the updating of *multiple* list items:

*Standard* way:

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
   item["LastReviewed"] = DateTime.Now;
   item.Update();
   ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Batched update:

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
   item["LastReviewed"] = DateTime.Now;
   item.Update();
}
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

> Note: in the second approach only a single batched request is
>   submitted to the server

**Complete example**

```
var listTitle = "Documents";
var folderUrl = "Archive/2013";

using (var ctx = GetContext(url, userName, password))
{
     //1. Get list items operation
     var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
     var items = list.GetListItems(folderUrl);
     ctx.Load(items);
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();


     //2. Update list items operation
     var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
     foreach (var item in items)
     {
           if(Convert.ToInt32(item["FSObjType"]) == 1) //skip folders
               continue;

           item["LastReviewed"] = DateTime.Now;
           item.Update();
           //ctx.ExecuteQuery();
           Console.WriteLine("{0} has been updated", item["FileRef"]);
     }
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();  //execute batched request
     watch.Stop();
     Console.WriteLine("Update operation completed: {0}", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds); 

     Console.ReadLine();
}
```

where `GetListItems` is the extension method for getting list items located under a specific folder:

```
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace SharePoint.Client.Extensions
{
    public static class ListCollectionExtensions
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Get list items located under specific folder 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="list"></param>
        /// <param name="relativeFolderUrl"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static ListItemCollection GetListItems(this List list, string relativeFolderUrl)
        {
            var ctx = list.Context;
            if (!list.IsPropertyAvailable("RootFolder"))
            {
                ctx.Load(list.RootFolder, f => f.ServerRelativeUrl);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            }
            var folderUrl = list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + relativeFolderUrl;
            var qry = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
            qry.FolderServerRelativeUrl = folderUrl;
            var items = list.GetItems(qry);
            return items;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  
I ran into 2 problems (maybe they are one) with your code. First I got an error stating that the request is too big and it should not be bigger then about 2Mb. I then build a counter that executes the query after X items. Which is definitely faster than my first appoach. is there a way to get the max amount of updates programmatically so i can get the best performance?
the other error was similar but it statet that I use too many resources.

Comment: Simon, that's indeed an expectable error when the request size is getting too big (2 Mb by default) and your approach (splitting batched requests) is correct. I will look into how to properly determine the current size of request and get back to you

Comment: Cool, thanks. What exactly does the line "if (!list.IsPropertyAvailable("RootFolder"))" do?  I want to also include the root folder in the update. How can I achieve this?

Comment: This expression in human language means: let's check if `RootFolder` property of List object is loaded (`FolderServerRelativeUrl` property has the following format `/[web]/[list or library]/[folder]` and `list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl` is intededed for getting list/library url ), if not then request it from the server

Comment: Thanks. One more question: my library is calles "Archive" and my folder is "Group1". So my folderUrl would be "Archive/Group1/" .With the current code, i will update all items below "Group1".What I want to do is also updating the folder "Group1". How can i achieve this?